# Low sound problems

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, pc

I've been looking 30-60min different links from Google to fix my problem, and still not succeeded.

1. I am using Windows XP (with Service Pack III)
2. I am using VIA Unknown @ nVIDIA MCP61 - High Definition Audio Controller.
3. The speakers I am using have a text on them: "Platinum UBL Series" (did a quick check in Google and didn't found anything useful)

One link talked about 5.1. I tried to set it on my speakers, but it jumps off it, so I believe either my speakers or my sound card cannot use that option.

One link talked about setting the [AudioMenu] fAudioMasterVolume in Skyrim_Default. What number I wanna put on it, the sound is always as low as always.

I hope there could be found a fix, which doesn't fit in "setting up another operating system" or "buying a new sound card or speakers".

Of course I could just raise up my speaker volume, but any other sound outside from Skyrim would put me go "boom head explosion", if you know what I mean.

Comment: You're certain that all of the volume controls are up in Skyrim's settings? I believe there are 4 of them, but I forget. How many speakers total do you have? 2 front ones? A center one? Any back ones? A sub? 5.1 means that you have 2 front speaker, 2 rear speakers, 1 center speaker and 1 sub.

Comment: All the volume controls I found in Skyrim has been in full. And yeah, I just got known today about the 5.1, and I need to say that I only have two speakers =D Didn't know that it meant several speakers.

Comment: Is it just Skyrim that you're having odd problems with the sound, or does this occur with other games? How do mp3's sound? Have you tried updated your soundcard drivers?

Comment: Skyrim is the only one. Sounds on other games are as they should be, and music works fine too. I don't believe it's about the sound drivers, but I could check it.

Comment: @Jagd Like Damaskox, I also have this issue. This happens in Skyrim only, and even with updated sound card drivers. Many other users have reported the same issue. Related Bethesda forums thread: [So... when will Bethesda fix the LOW SOUND issue?](http://forums.bethsoft.com/topic/1351097-so-when-will-bethesda-fix-the-low-sound-issue/)

Comment: It's a fairly known issue, I had the same thing I fixed it in Windows 7 by raising the volume of just the Skyrim application. I know that is not possible in Windows XP.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way of fixing it in Windows 7 is just raising the application volume.

Since you are using Windows XP, however the best solution would be to modify the .ini file.  Located in:

```
My Documents\My Games\Skyrim\SkyrimPrefs.ini
```

Open the file and find the line that says:

```
fAudioMasterVolume=1.000
```

Adjust that to something higher let's say 2.000 should be sufficient for your needs.

Comment: …does that *work*? Does the engine actually honour a 200% volume setting, or does it just ignore out-of-bounds numbers, like it does for most ini settings?

Comment: The engine I'm sure supports it. The options in the game probably do not, and would probably be reset to the 1.0 value if you modify them.